# Why does the quran say homosexuality first existed during Prophet Lot's time?

Tags: quran, prophets

SAHIH INTERNATIONAL
And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Indeed, you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds.
Quran 29:28

Clearly homosexuals and homosexual existed before then? Clearly rape existed before their time, considering Lot's people raped travellers. 
So can someone explain?

http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/29/28

'Allah tells us that His Prophet Lut, peace be upon him, denounced his people for their evil deed and their immoral actions in having intercourse with males, a deed which none of the sons of Adam had ever committed before them. As well as doing this, they also disbelieved in Allah and rejected and opposed His Messenger, they robbed wayfarers, they would lie in wait on the road, kill people and loot their possessions.'

Comment: "Clearly"? Based on what exactly are you making that assumption?

Comment: there were other civilizations before them thousands of years before Lot's people of recorded homosexuality.

Comment: @janakar which civilizations? You should share an evidence to support your claims that these civilizations recorded homosexuality.

Answer (score 2):

There is no answer for this question, we have no concrete evidence about what happened before Lot's time...

And even **if** it was found that there were homosexuals before Lot, then it's **false** . Apart from being non-validated, it contradicts what Allah said, and as Allah also said :

> “Who is more knowledgeable: you or Allah?” [2:140]

So it's not our job to claim the falsehood of the Quran based on our useless assumptions.